# Oracle: How to load hierachical JSON data into related tables

Tags: json, oracle, oracle19c

I have got JSON data in a JSON column of an Oracle database. The JSON contains arrays and I should load the data into tables by means of PL/SQL. E. g.

```
{
  "A1": "V1",
  "A2": true,
  "A3": 42,
  "A4": [
    {
      "B1": "Q1",
      "B4": [
        {
          "C1": "R1",
          "C2": false
        },
        {
          "C1": "R2",
          "C2": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "B1": "Q2",
      "B4": [
        {
          "C1": "R3",
          "C2": false
        },
        {
          "C1": "R4",
          "C2": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "A1": "V2",
  "A2": false,
  "A3": 42,
  "A4": [
    {
      "B1": "T1",
      "B4": [
        {
          "C1": "S1",
          "C2": false
        },
        {
          "C1": "S2",
          "C2": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "B1": "T2",
      "B4": [
        {
          "C1": "S3",
          "C2": false
        },
        {
          "C1": "S4",
          "C2": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The data should be loaded to three tables.

> ```
>        ---
>         A
>        ---
>         | 0..1
>         |
>         | 1..n
>        ---
>         B (no (business) key available)
>        ---
>         | 0..1
>         |
>         | 1..n
>        ---
>         C
>        ---
> ```

| ID | A1 | A2 | A3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | V1 | true | 42 |
| 2 | V2 | false | 42 |

| ID | ID A | B1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Q1 |
| 2 | 1 | Q2 |
| 3 | 2 | T1 |
| 4 | 2 | T2 |

| ID | ID B | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | R1 | false |
| 2 | 1 | R2 | false |
| 3 | 1 | R3 | false |
| 4 | 1 | R4 | true |
| 5 | 2 | S1 | false |
| 6 | 2 | S2 | false |
| 7 | 2 | S3 | false |
| 8 | 2 | S4 | true |

I am trying to use `JSON_TABLE` to flatten the data for an implicit cursor of a for loop. I did so by using `NESTED PATH`. Now imagine we are in the for loop, i.e. for every "record" in C there is a record in the cursor/loop. While the data of C is "as is", the data of B gets mimeographed, and the data of A likewise, i.e.

| A1 | A2 | A3 | B1 | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| V1 | true | 42 | Q1 | R1 | false |
| V1 | true | 42 | Q1 | R2 | false |
| V1 | true | 42 | Q2 | R3 | false |
| V1 | true | 42 | Q2 | R4 | true |
| V2 | false | 42 | T1 | S1 | false |
| V2 | false | 42 | T1 | S2 | false |
| V2 | false | 42 | T2 | S3 | false |
| V2 | false | 42 | T2 | S4 | true |

My initial idea was to insert from the "A" data into table "A" only the first occurrence of a A-tuple saving the written ID by `RETURNING .. INTO`, insert the first occurrence of a B-tuple into "B" saving the written ID likewise and finally insert the C-tuple into "C". The problem here is to detect the change of the A-tuple respectively of the B-tuple. "A" should not be too much of a difficulty as it has a (business) key I also can preserve for checks. However, B has no (business) key.
My idea with B was to use an unknown, maybe inexistent pseudo column `JSON_TABLE`/`NESTED PATH` provides, that tells e.g. to which expression of "B" the current "C" belongs to. In fact, it would be a key for "B". Yet, I have not found anything in the Oracle docs and on the internet. Do you happen to know such a column?

As an alternative, I think about not using the `NESTED PATH` for "C" but return the array as JSON column and afterwards to somehow create an inner for loop, but I do not know how to use a JSON typed PL/SQL variable to extract an array of objects as nested table of some sort to be able to use as for loop cursor. Do you happen to know examples for such?

Is there a way, I miss completely?

Kind regards

Thiemo

Comment: You may add some FOR ORDINALITY columns to help parsing of the returned rows: each one at A,B,C levels.

Comment: @p3consulting: Great hint. I shall try on Monday. Thanks.

Comment: @p3consulting Thanks again for the hint. It did not resolve my problem entirely. FOR ORDINALITY is a counter of the array element present. Together with a first business key, I could make my code work.